# Automatically elaborate an external table's data

Tags: external-files, automation, parsing

I have to create a serie of sheets with LaTeX using informations from a LibreOffice table (but I can convert it in other formats if needed). The problem is, the table is some hundreds rows long, so it would take much time to copy, not to tell about misspellings and other mistakes, so I'm wondering if there is a way to tell LaTeX to automatically fill a form for each line of my table, considering that it can contain complex strings, e. g. with punctuation, parentheses, digits or multiple lines.

I haven't written any code yet, so each suggestion is good.

I have absolutely no idea if such a thing is possible, please take pity if that's a crazy request =)

---

### Example (much simpler than the real situation)

Let's say my table contains datas about people: name, surname, age, a profile image (represented with its relative path, so I can treat it as a string) and some details. The last field can take multiple lines that must be kept, or at least the line break should be turned in a space (" ").

[image]

From that table I want to create a sort of identity card for each person:

[image]

*(corner picture from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Halictus_bee_on_flower-2.jpg))*

And I want to do that without writing the same code for each row of my table.

Comment: can you export the table from libreoffice to csv text file (or any other format?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Absolutely. Just consider that some fields can contain commas, new lines or other (potentially) problematic characters (but I don't know if it actually is a problem).

Comment: yes but presumably libreoffice quotes them in some way eg every cell is in `"...,..."` quotes to hide the commas. Once you have the csv file lots of answers on this site give ways of reading it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv